# $SU(2)$ and its representations

Tags: lie-algebras

Does the Lie-Algebra of $SU(2)$ always have 3 generators? Because I'm reading about different representations of $SU(2)$ as $2\times2$, $3\times3$, $4\times4$ matrices etc. But I guess that even if we are looking at $7\times7$ matrix representation of $SU(2)$ we only need $3$ such matrices corresponding to the $3$ generators right?

And if we have a representation by say $7\times 7$ matrices, is it not possible by using similarity transformations to find an $3-$dimensional invariant subspace corresponding to these $3$ linear operators? Then what point is it to look for higher representations of $SU(2)$ then just $3\times 3$ real matrices?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you are correct in your first guess: the image of the representation is (unless it's trivial) isomorphic to $SU(2)$ (and the analogous fact would hold true for any simple Lie algebra) and hence has three generators. However, with your final question, you seem to be basically asking **what is the point of representation theory, if the represented group or Lie algebra is already given as a matrix group or Lie algebra?**. That's a valid but very broad question which has nothing to do with $SU(2)$ in particular.

Comment: And let me add to my above comment that that exact question was asked, and got some very insightful answers, on MathOverflow: https://mathoverflow.net/q/153740/27465

Comment: It is not true that every $7$-dimensional representation of SU$(2)$ has a $3$-dimensional invariant subspace. SU$(2)$ has an irreducible $7$-dimensional representation.

Comment: ok, so given any set of 3 linearly independent 7x7 matrices, it is not true that you by a change of coordinates can find an invariant subspace with a lower dimension then 7? I find this interesting because then it makes a big difference by how you choose your set of 3 linearly independent matrices. Because I could obviously choose them such that there is an invariant 3 dimensional subspace which they act on.

Comment: Higgsino, to find an invariant subspace for the generators of a representation means to find a subrepresentation. Given that representations of semisimple Lie algebras are completely reducible, saying that one is *irreducible* is equivalent to *it has no proper subrepresentation / there is no proper invariant subspace*.